# Is it possible for a dynamic feature module to depend on another dynamic feature module?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have a modular project which contains a base module (base) and two others modules (A & B) which depends on base. It works.

Now, I want to add a new module C which depends on B and base.

So I create a dynamic feature module C and add this in its build.gradle :

```
implementation project(':base')
implementation project(':B')
```

But C can't access B resources. For example, if I put some dimensions in the dimens.xml file of B, C can't access these dimensions. I have a "Android resource linking failed" error.

Do I need to add more code than the "implementation project" in order to make this works ?

Comment: is it instant-enabled feature module ?

Answer (score 0):

If this error is coming from your xml, then unfortunately, xml is limited in this way. You are recommended to place your resources in your base and/or moduleC itself.

However, if you're doing it in runtime, you can point to moduleB's dimens resources by using `com.sample.moduleb.R.dimen.some_margin`

Regardless, it's recommended to either have your resources in the base module or the calling module itself, because what if the other module isn't instant-installed yet? (which is an entirely likely scenario for instant apps)